# passing defined object to another custom directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have this custom directives that you could see below.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function (testService) {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        link:function (scope, element, attr) {
           //defined the object
           var object = new object();
           testService.setObject(object);
    }
   }
});

myApp.directive('mySecondDirective', function (testService) {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        link:function (scope, element, attr) {
           //call the variable from previous custom directive
           console.log(testService.getobject()); -> always return undefined
    }
   }
});
```

and this is the html structure where I used the directives above.

```
<my-directive></my-directive>

<my-second-directive></my-second-directive>
```

there I want to retreive the `object` that contains `new object()` from previous custom directive, but it always return an `undefined` I wonder how could I do this without using **require** nor **isolated scope** as well.. could you guys help me ?

**UPDATE**
I create a service to provide the facility to set and retreive the object and apparently it returned undefined because I set the custom direcitve this way

```
<my-second-directive></my-second-directive>

<my-directive></my-directive>
```

and this is the service

```
define(
        ['services/services'],
        function(services)
        {
            'use strict';

            services.factory('testService', [function() {
                    var me = this;
                    var testObject = '';

                    return {
                        setObject: function(object) {
                            me.testObject = object;
                        },
                        getObject: function() {
                            return me.testObject;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
        }
);
```

the thing is that I actually set the html markup like I already mentioned above which is

```
<my-second-directive></my-second-directive>

<my-directive></my-directive>
```

so could you give me some advice on how should I do this ?

note* that the passing object actually worked I prefer using services because it will easy to mantain latter. The question is how do I make the object accessible from another directive even though the initiate install of the object (set the object) in the directive that I defined at the html markup, as the last position of the html it self ?

**UPDATE** this is the **[`PLUNKER`](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnDYxyzSWSQLplCDbI6Y?p=preview)** that I've been made for you to understand the question it self

Comment: Try using scope.object = new object(); in the first directive. Access the same in second directive using scope.object

Comment: already tried it but still returned with undefined response :( @SrinivasPaila

Comment: please have a look at the question, I already update some

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: I create a plunker for this please have a look http://plnkr.co/edit/JnDYxyzSWSQLplCDbI6Y?p=preview @SrinivasPaila

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by firing a custom event and then listening for it in the second directive.  Here's an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/512gi6mfepyc04JKfiep?p=info

Broadcast the event from the first directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(testService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      var object = {};
      testService.setObject(object);
      console.log('setting object');
      scope.$broadcast('objectSet');
    }
  }
});
```

... and then listen for it on the second:

```
app.directive('mySecondDirective', function(testService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      scope.$on('objectSet', function(){
        console.log('retrieving object', testService.getObject());
      })
    }
  }
});
```

You could also pass data along with the event, if you wanted to emit a specific piece of data to be picked up by the second directive.

Comment: yes it worked but it wrapped inside the $on functionality, whereas what I wanted is use it inside the directive it self.. I update the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kALqqab9Qu24Hl78gPls?p=preview could you give me some advice regarding this issue ? @gmartellino

Answer (score 0):

**1). Scope**. Since you don't want to use controllers and isolated scope, then you can simply set this object as scope property.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            var object = {};
            object.test = 21;

            // set object as scope property
            scope.object = object;
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('mySecondDirective', function() {
    return {
        priority: 1,  // priority is important here
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log('Retrieve: ', scope.object);
        }
    }
});
```

Just make sure you are also defining `priority` on the second directive (only if both directive a applied to the same element) to make sure it's evaluated in proper turn (should be bigger then the one of `myDirective`, if omitted it's `0`).

**2). Service**. Another simple solution is to use service. You can inject custom service into both directives and use it storage for you shared object.

Comment: yap already sets the priority as well but still returned with undefined response :( @dfsq

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from what @gmartellino said.

Anything that you wanted to do after listening to the event in second directive, can have a callBack method and use it.

```
app.directive('mySecondDirective', function(testService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      // what if I created like this ? 
      // define the test variable
      var test;

      scope.$on('objectSet', function(){
        //set the variable
        test = testService.getObject();
        console.log('retrieving object : ', testService.getObject());

        //Anything that you wanted to do 
        //after listening to the event 
        //Write a callBack method and call it
        codeToExecuteAsCallBack();
      })

      //then use this method to make a call back from the event 
      //and outside the event too.
      var codeToExecuteAsCallBack = function(){
        console.log(test);
      }
      codeToExecuteAsCallBack();
    }
  }
});
```

Updated plnkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/FzPms43Ii1TgEWBLJPft?p=preview)